Two MAC addresses on a single network, and on a single computer (NEW TWIST OLDISH QUERY)
I have found many questions addressing how there CAN NOT be two exact MAC addresses on a network, technically in the world. The similar example is the postman, and having two houses with the same address just does not work ever. (UNDERSTOOD)
Okay, so here is the problem.
I have a computer, one computer. It has a wireless card (0C-27-15-33-3A-56) and it has an Ethernet card (0C-27-15-33-99-99).
We then installed a very specific piece of medical software that binds its security key to the address running when the software was installed. In this case it was wireless as they had not punched down the Ethernet wall jacks at the site.
I get the keys the company generated, by this time the company punches down the Ethernet and the IT group plugs in the Ethernet and disables the wireless.
MAC address changes and the hardware fingerprint slightly changes and BAM the keys are invalid, and the software won't run. Change back to wireless and voilà the software runs again.
So I spoofed the Ethernet to be the same as the Wireless. Each has (0C-27-15-33-3A-56) as the mac address. (MAC names have been changed to protect the innocent)
So my question is simple. The White Lines of this issue is the Ethernet and the wireless will never (or should never) be running at the same time.
Using the postman analogy, It's like having only one house and having a blue mailbox and a green mailbox with the same address at the same house and only allowing one to be used at a time.
What am I messing if anything that would make this an issue. I do understand that if the wireless "accidentally" gets enabled while the Ethernet is also running, that will be an issue.
I am looking at using global policies to lock down, enabling the wireless, so this accident can not happen.
Thoughts.

What am I messing engaging the vendor.

The software vendor must have a process for relicensing when replacing network cards in machines or even replacing the whole machine. Is this because you have a large fleet of machines (a full hospital) or just one specific machine/office?

Disable the Wireless network adapter in the BIOS (preferred), or in Device Manager.

Yea I can engage the vendor, yes they can solve the issue by reissuing the key for the other Mac. 24-48 hrs.
I always have a wireless and wired NIC in wanting to have a single procedure for this issue.
Also did not mention last version of software did not look at Mac as a factor that would “break” the keys. You could switch nics and nothing happened.


We then installed a very specific piece of medical software that binds its security key to the address running when the software was installed.

The vendor needs to have some procedure to rebind the software to another MAC address.

I do understand that if the wireless "accidentally" gets enabled while the Ethernet is also running, that will be an issue.

Just change the Wifi MAC address to something else as well. You could use the now free Ethernet MAC, but if things go south it might get reset by accident. I'd recommend using a locally administered MAC address (LAA) that's not in public use. Just make sure the two lowest bits of the first octet are 10 (the octet needs to end in -2,-6,-A or -E) with the rest just about anything/random and you'll be fine.
Alternatively, leave the Wifi activated and just don't connect anywhere.

After doing some reading I think this may be my go to idea. Create a virtual nic and point both hardware mics at the virtual.
I have enough service calls about IT companies that change stuff and it breaks the software and their in a panic to get it fixed fast.
